# How to use an integrated extension function from the command line with Saxon-HE

Tags: java, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am trying to use a [custom integrated extension function](https://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions/ext-full-J.html) with Saxon-HE 9.9.1.5 run from the command line. When making the call, I get an error that the function cannot be found (`XPST0017: Cannot find a 0-argument function named Q{http://ramsen.no/saxon-extensions}random()`).

I have tried to set up a simple project, following the instructions in the Saxon documentation. I have these files:

- pom.xml
- hello.xml
- hello-world.xml
- src/main/java/no/ramsen/Transform.java
- src/main/java/no/ramsen/extensions/Random.java

After building with Maven, I am trying to perform the transformation with this command. I built the jar with all dependencies (`maven-assembly-plugin` with `jar-with-dependencies`), so everything should be included. I also set the main java class to be `no.ramsen.Transform`.

```
java -jar target/integratedExtensionTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -TJ -t -s:hello.xml -xsl:hello-world.xsl
```

## Pom file

```xml
<!-- Abbreviated... -->
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
    <version>9.9.1-5</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- Abbreviated... -->
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>no.ramsen.Transform</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

## hello.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hello></hello>
```

## hello-world.xsl

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ramsen="http://ramsen.no/saxon-extensions">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text>Hello, </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ramsen:random()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## src/main/java/no/ramsen/Transform.java

```java
public class Transform extends net.sf.saxon.Transform {
    @Override
    protected void applyLocalOptions(CommandLineOptions options, Configuration config) {
        config.registerExtensionFunction(new Random());
        super.applyLocalOptions(options, config);
    }
}
```

## src/main/java/no/ramsen/extensions/Random.java

```java
public class Random extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition {
    @Override
    public StructuredQName getFunctionQName() {
        return new StructuredQName("ramsen", "http://ramsen.no/saxon-extensions", "random");
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes() {
        return new SequenceType[] {};
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType getResultType(SequenceType[] sequenceTypes) {
        return SequenceType.SINGLE_DOUBLE;
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression() {
        return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {
            @Override
            public Sequence call(XPathContext xPathContext, Sequence[] sequences) {
                return DoubleValue.makeDoubleValue(Math.random());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I would expect to get a result transformation, something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hello>Hello, 0.5</hello>
```

Instead I get an error message:

```
Saxon-HE 9.9.1.5J from Saxonica
Java version 11.0.5
Looking for function Q{http://ramsen.no/saxon-extensions}random#0
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.registry.XSLT30FunctionSet
Trying net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetFunctionLibrary
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.FunctionLibraryList
Looking for function Q{http://ramsen.no/saxon-extensions}random#0
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.registry.VendorFunctionSetHE
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.MathFunctionSet
Trying net.sf.saxon.ma.map.MapFunctionSet
Trying net.sf.saxon.ma.arrays.ArrayFunctionSet
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.registry.ExsltCommonFunctionSet
Function Q{http://ramsen.no/saxon-extensions}random not found!
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.registry.ConstructorFunctionLibrary
Trying net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryFunctionLibrary
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.IntegratedFunctionLibrary
Trying net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetFunctionLibrary
Function Q{http://ramsen.no/saxon-extensions}random not found!
Static error in {ramsen:random()} in expression in xsl:value-of/@select on line 8 column 54 of hello-world.xsl:
  XPST0017: Cannot find a 0-argument function named Q{http://ramsen.no/saxon-extensions}random()
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
```

Using IntelliJ, I set a breakpoint within the `src/main/java/no/ramsen/Transform.java` file, in the `applyLocalOptions` method. This breakpoint is never reached; I suspect I have not succeeded in actually registering my extension function?

Comment: It looks to me as it is simply `net.sf.saxon.Transform` that is run. Don't you need a main method for your `Transform` class that instantiates its own instance and the calls `doTransform`?

Comment: Of course, @MartinHonnen. That was the solution! I had an incorrect understanding of inheritance; I thought a subclass and overriding the `applyLocalOptions` method was enough.